# Cannot partition internal SSD High Sierra

Tags: disk-utility, high-sierra

I wanted to install MacOS Mojave on a new partition just to check it out. But I cant partition my internal drive using disk utility. I'm running High Sierra 10.13.5. I've included a screenshot of disk utility.

Any suggestions?[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am deleting the answer soon can you please move all information in comments to your question.

Answer (score 1):

**No room**

The answer is in your screenshot.

Macintosh HD is too full and as a result partitioning the drive would result in a partition too small.

**First Screenshot:**
*“This volume can’t be split because the resulting volumes would be too small”*

You need to clear out some space on Macintosh HD by deleting some files. [This](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht206996) may help with that, but please know 256GB computer is very small and is not meant to be partitioned to run two OS’s. Can it be done? Yes, but you are basically going to me limited to a couple files on each OS.

**I would just suggest installing macOS Mojave on a partition on an external drive (such as the one in your screenshot).**

Comment: I have 120 GB free. I've done this multiple times over the years to test out new OSX versions. This is the 1st time I can't partition the drive. You only need 30-50 GB to run an OS on another partition comfortably. You dont have to split the hard drive in half.

Comment: @user293152 Can you post a screenshot of Macintosh HD in disk utility? And the terminal output of “diskutil list”?

Comment: I just added the screenshots to the original post

Comment: @user293152 Look at the new disk-utility screenshot. “41GB” available.

Comment: 82 GB is purgeable. According to Apple thats free space. I tried this a few days ago also when I had 70 GB free (+70 purgeable). It still didn't work.

Comment: Instead of partitioning can I just add another Volume and install to that?

Comment: @user293152 What if you lower the number in the first screenshot? I’m guessing it won’t let you apply but can you try?

Comment: Resets back to 250

Comment: @user293152 Can you post a screenshot of the * partition in the first screenshot?

Comment: It's the Apple Kernel Core Dump 655 MB

Answer (score -2):

boot the macos from recovery partition and go to disk utility from you should be able to make one partition as per the requirement. Since the disk is full you will not able to partition from the same drive and before processing to partition, you need to take an back up and delete unwanted files on the drive

Comment: Disk is not full as mentioned above. Same problem when booting into recovery partition, disk utility says the exact thing as above